# EDID information on Android

Tags: android, edid

I need to get display information connected to my android device via hdmi. 
I used DisplayManager to get the Display information but i am unable to get the vendor information from it. 
What i understand is that, this kind of information can be retrieved from Extended Display Identification Data(EDID). Is there any api or a way to get this data and parse it in android?

Android version i am working with is 4.0+